# Vim edit http netrw

Tags: http, vim, netrw

In pseudo speak: I use a command:

> edit! http://apath/toapage.pg1.html

and with the elinks plugin this will open the contents of this page into a buffer for editing

But when I try to increment this url's "1" by injecting a function variable (funcvar), such as:

```
let @a = 'http://apath/toapage.pg' .a:funcvar. '.html' 
edit! @a
```

If fails, even though checking the reg a shows it to be exactly the same characters.

Does anyone know why?

(Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`edit! @a` doesn't expand `@a`

Please try:

```
exec 'e! ' . @a
```